# ec2-bundle-vol Chunking Size

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Making an AMI and storing it to S3 using the ec2-bundle-vol/ec2-upload-bundle/ec2-register trifecta in AWS I get 36 10 MB image chunks.  For a readability/testing standpoint I would much prefer something like 4 100 MB images or one 3.5 GB file.

I am not seeing an easy way to change this behavior without finding and reverse-engineering the Ruby Rails script wrapped in ec2-bundle-vol.

Alternately, is there a good reason for three dozen small files?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there's no way without modifying the ruby script.
The chunk size is hardcoded

$AWS_PATH/amitools/ec2/lib/ec2/amitools/bundle.rb **line 14**

```
CHUNK_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024 # 10 MB in bytes.
```

Eventually, it might not work to register the bundle if chunks have a different size